# how to select unique tuples from same table

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I want to find all pairs of diffrent students that are enrolled in two or more sections together from

enroll(sid*, grade, dname*, cno*, sectno*)

where each section is uniquely identified by (dname*, cno*, sectno*)

Answer (score 3):

You can self join on the columns that identify a section and specify `e1.sid < e2.sid` to fetch each pair of students only once.

```
select e1.sid, e2.sid from enroll e1
join enroll e2 on e1.dname = e2.dname
and e1.cno = e2.cno
and e1.secno = e2.sectno
where e1.sid < e2.sid
group by e1.sid, e2.sid
having count(*) > 1
```

Comment: but i want the pair of sudents to be enrolled in 2 or more sections together. the above query gives a pair enrolled in one section together

Comment: @anvitapotluri see update, instead of `distinct` use `group by` and `having`

Answer (score 1):

```
/*
with enroll as (
select 1 sid, 'dname' dname, 1 cno, 1 secno from dual union all
select 1 sid, 'dname' dname, 1 cno, 1 secno from dual union all
select 2 sid, 'dname' dname, 1 cno, 1 secno from dual union all
select 3 sid, 'dname' dname, 1 cno, 1 secno from dual union all
select 1 sid, 'dname' dname, 2 cno, 2 secno from dual union all
select 2 sid, 'dname' dname, 2 cno, 2 secno from dual
)
*/
select e1.sid, e2.sid from enroll e1
join enroll e2 on e1.dname = e2.dname
and e1.cno = e2.cno
and e1.secno = e2.secno
where e1.sid < e2.sid
group by e1.sid, e2.sid
having count(*) >= 2;
```

(But this query won't work correctly if one sid enrolled on the same section more then once)

Answer (score 1):

```
with enroll as (
select 1 sid, 'dname' dname, 1 cno, 1 secno from dual union all
select 1 sid, 'dname' dname, 1 cno, 1 secno from dual union all
select 2 sid, 'dname' dname, 1 cno, 1 secno from dual union all
select 3 sid, 'dname' dname, 1 cno, 1 secno from dual union all
select 3 sid, 'dname' dname, 1 cno, 1 secno from dual union all
select 1 sid, 'dname' dname, 2 cno, 2 secno from dual union all
select 2 sid, 'dname' dname, 2 cno, 2 secno from dual
)
select rn,sid from (
select row_number() over (partition by sid order by dname) as rn ,sid
from enroll ) 
where rn>1
```

**use row_number()**

this query work correctly if one sid enrolled on the same section more then once

---

distinct can be used if required

```
with enroll as (
select 1 sid, 'dname' dname, 1 cno, 1 secno from dual union all
select 1 sid, 'dname' dname, 1 cno, 1 secno from dual union all
select 2 sid, 'dname' dname, 1 cno, 1 secno from dual union all
select 3 sid, 'dname' dname, 1 cno, 1 secno from dual union all
select 3 sid, 'dname' dname, 1 cno, 1 secno from dual union all
select 1 sid, 'dname' dname, 2 cno, 2 secno from dual union all
select 4 sid, 'dname' dname, 2 cno, 2 secno from dual union all
select 2 sid, 'dname' dname, 2 cno, 2 secno from dual
)
select distinct  sid from (
select row_number() over (partition by sid order by dname) as rn ,sid
from enroll ) 
where rn>1
```

**Output**

```
>        SID
> ----------
>          1
>          2
>          3
```